# How to set the text in a label to a name in database using log-in as key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

I have 2 ASP.NET webpages, a log-in page and the main page. What I want to do is after I log-in, it would save the ID into the session then use that to retrieve the first name of the user from a database (same table as ID) and into a label on the main page. I was able to do it in the past using:

```
SqlDataReader
```

But now I have a Data Access Layer class that returns a:

```
DataTable
```

There's my problem. I can't seem to figure out how to do it. So far, I have these pieces:

```
Session.Add("StudentID", dt);
```

That was for the log-in page. Here's for the main page:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["StudentUser"];
int ID = int.Parse(Session["StudentID"].ToString());
DAL.GetData("SELECT Fname FROM StudentUser WHERE StudentID = " + ID);
lblName.Text = dt["Fname"].ToString();
```

As for my DAL codes, here they are:

```
public static DataTable GetData(string sql)
{
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DAL.ConnectionString);
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      da.Fill(dt);
      return dt;
}
```

My table is called `StudentUser` and the part I want on the label is `Fname`

When using `SqlDataReader` (dr) the code for the log-in normally looks like this:

```
Session.Add("StudentID", dr["StudentID"].ToString());
```

And for the main page:

```
int ID = int.Parse(Session["StudentID"].ToString());
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Fname FROM StudentUser WHERE StudentID = " + ID, con);
SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
lblName.Text = dr["Fname"].ToString();
dr.Close();
```

The `SqlDataReader` code work, but I am determined to use my Data Access Layer whenever possible, even if it leads me to use code that I am unfamiliar with. Please help dear people. :)

Comment: What does your login code look like?

Comment: @DGibbs
Login button code:
...
DataTable dt = DAL.GetData("SELECT * FROM StudentUser WHERE StudentID =" + txtID.Text);
...some error checking codes...
if (txtPW.Text == dt.Rows[0][1].ToString());
{
Session.Add("StudentID", dt);       Response.Redirect("ApplyBlueform.aspx");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you can't use one method for all possibilities. In your example for one, you have no way to send a parameter to your dal, that means you'd have to create a method in your dal for such a thing.

I have a class that does more or less what you want. It's not a proper repository but for beginners it may have what you need.

http://pastebin.com/xYhsSeXW

Comment: Your suggestion worked wonderfully. I created a new method on my Data Access Layer that returns a SqlDataReader value. Plugging-in this newly created method into the webpage code then some coding and there, I now have the first name displaying in the label. Thank you everyone for helping out, cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method `DAL.GetData`, but you're not saving the `DataTable` anywhere.., why don't you try this:

```
DataTable dt1 = DAL.GetData("SELECT Fname FROM StudentUser WHERE StudentID = " + ID);
lblName.Text = dt1["Fname"].ToString();
```

Instead of:

```
DAL.GetData("SELECT Fname FROM StudentUser WHERE StudentID = " + ID);
lblName.Text = dt["Fname"].ToString();
```

You need to store the value that is returned from the method that you created if not it makes no sense to call that method.

Comment: This gave me an error: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable'"